# JQuery Compare select siblings values

Tags: jquery, select, siblings

I have 10 dropdown menus, each with 30 or so options. I'm trying to prevent the same value being selected in any of the menus by using JQuery to compare each select value to its siblings. Here's my code, but it ain't workin:

```
$('#select1').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).siblings().val()) {
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

As you can see I'm trying to compare the value of `#select1` against all it's siblings by using `$(this).siblings().val()`. Can't figure out why this won't work.

Comment: `$(this).siblings().val()` will only give you the value of one the sibling. [doc](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1), try using each() to go through all the siblings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think siblings return a list of elements not a single item, so you need to run a loop

```
$('#select1').change(function() {

    var $select = $(this);

    $(this).siblings().each(function(index){

        if ($(this).val() == $select.val()) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#select1').change(function() {
    var self = this, 
        t = $(this).siblings().filter(function() {
            return this.value == self.value;
        });
    if (t.length) {
        alert("OK");
    }
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/X8L2E/)

Answer (score 1):

try using [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
$('#select1').change(function() {

    var arr=[];
    $.each($(this).siblings(),function(i,j){
     arr.push($(j).val());
    });
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(),arr)) {
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

Comment: Firstly, there's a syntax error in your code, your missing the closing parenthesis in your `if` statement, secondly, `val()` "gets the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements", so even though `siblings()` will create an array, using val() will only get the value of the first element in that collection. As it stands this does not work at all?